# Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Not relevant to click event)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, linkedin-api

**This is traceback code.**

```
2021-10-04 18:21:53.294724 : ERROR : Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
(Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.80,platform=Linux 4.9.230-76 aarch64)

2021-10-04 18:21:53.319382 : ERROR : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/linkedin/crawler.py", line 143, in main_loop
self.main_process()
File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/linkedin/crawler.py", line 73, in main_process
if self.message_updated():
File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/linkedin/crawler.py", line 54, in message_updated
now = get_last_messages(self.driver, self.db)
File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/linkedin/message/parse/conversation.py", line 310, in get_last_messages
i.find_elements_by_class_name("msg-conversation-card__title-row")[0]) for i in members if
File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/linkedin/message/parse/conversation.py", line 311, in <listcomp>
len(i.find_elements_by_class_name("msg-conversation-card__message-snippet-body"))]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 413, in find_elements_by_class_name
return self.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 685, in find_elements
{"using": by, "value": value})['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
(Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.80,platform=Linux 4.9.230-76 aarch64)


2021-10-04 18:21:53.356802 : INFO : Device shutdown.
```

**This is block code that got error**

```
def get_last_messages(driver: WebDriver, db: Db):
    safe_open(driver, "https://www.linkedin.com/messaging", db)
    members = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("msg-conversation-listitem")
    temp = [(i.find_elements_by_class_name("msg-conversation-card__message-snippet-body")[0],
             i.find_elements_by_class_name("msg-conversation-card__title-row")[0]) for i in members if
            len(i.find_elements_by_class_name("msg-conversation-card__message-snippet-body"))]
    cards = [(i[0].text, none_or_value(i[1].find_elements_by_tag_name("time"))) for i in temp]
    return [(i[0], i[1].text) for i in cards if i[1]]
```

Do you guy know what wrongs here, because I expected that this function "find_elements_by..." will return empty array [] when there are nothing to get, but here this throw exception.
Thank you guy for helping me so much!

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementReferenceException will be occurs only when your element is not present(vanished or not constructed till) in your website. please add wait conditions to check the visibility of the element.

```
By optionXpath = By.xpath("your xpath fp goes here !");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(optionXpath));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(optionXpath));
driver.findElement(optionXpath).click();
```

**In case of not constructed :**

> you need to add wait conditions

**In case of vanished :**

> yours actions on element is wrong. add screenshot just before your
> failure code and recheck your code.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, sir. But I just wonder that I don't perform any action in this element (click or something else). I just get the elements with "find_elements" func => I should be returned [] if there are not existed. But why did I get this exception?
In case it was vanished it should have return [] instead of Exception, right? Sorry if I got any misunderstanding your words/

Comment: But you have mentioned oth index in your method, 
find_elements_by_class_name("msg-conversation-card__message-snippet-body")[0],

Comment: So, if array return [], but I access to 0th element => it should return "list out of range" exception, shouldn't it?

Comment: Here the case is, element is there not empty [] but not attached to the main html page. better add wait time(i hope this will resolve) and take screenshot for debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get your point. If it's not empty it should return something instead of this exception? I think if it's not attached to the main html page => it should return []. Can you explain in detail? Sorry for this inconvience. And sorry I can debug this one because it just appear sometimes, I can't reproduce it .